# Formula to subtract the latest entered value in a column from a fixed cell/value in the same column

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column in excel with the very top cell being where I want my result to print,  the cell below that is where my initial/fixed value is located.  I will be making ongoing entries in the the cells in the lower rows in the same column and want to subtract only the latest entry from the initial fixed value at the top of the column.

I do have the current date in another cell using the =TODAY() function, not sure if that is useful or if there is a simpler formula to keep everything in the same column.

Thanks in advance for any help.
ConfusedBySelf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INDEX/MATCH to return the last numeric value in a column:

```
=B2-INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))
```

[image]

Comment: That's awesome Scott.  Works a treat, thank you for your quick reply  :-)

Comment: @ConfusedBySelf please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.